# Angular .controller() runs before .run()

Tags: angularjs, controller, dependencies

I have an ajax call inside the .run() that loads a variable into the $rootScope
That variable is needed in the controller associated with a view.

Sometimes on refresh (F5) by the time the .controller is loading there is nothing inside $rootScope.user.fedUnit resulting in:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'fedUnit' of undefined

Any way to delay loading the controller until after the .run() is finished?
Can't seem to find it.

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $http, $location, SessionFactory, TokenHandler) {
    token = TokenHandler.getToken();
    if ( token != null ) {
        SessionFactory.get( { token : token },
            function success(response, responseHeaders) {
                $rootScope.user = response;
            }
        );
    }
});

app.controller('UnitController', function($scope, $rootScope, $location, UnitFactory) {
    $scope.updateUnits = function () {
        UnitFactory.query({fedUnit: $rootScope.user.fedUnit}, function success(response, responseHeaders) { ...
```

**Solution**

```
$rootScope.foo = $q.defer();
$rootScope.foo.resolve(); when AJAX is done;
$rootScope.foo.promise.then(..) in the controller.
```

thanks to @misterhiller (twitter)

Comment: I feel that your `run()` has actually finished before the controller loads - its just that the run() seems to contain an asynchronous call - It is called and forgotten until it returns, while the browser proceeds with the execution of the next set of code - in the process calling your controller - since the GET request still would not have returned (in that split second) and thus results in the error - Could you post the code for the `SessionFactory` service?

Comment: You need to make this work asynchronously. Create a provider which loads performs the AJAX request.

Comment: Yes, The Sessionfactory is a simple $resource call to some sort of rest API.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. That safed my day. So i added a functional code sample.

Answer (score 7):

The solution at functional code block:

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $http, $q, SessionFactory, TokenHandler) {

    $rootScope.ajaxCall = $q.defer();

    token = TokenHandler.getToken();
    if ( token != null ) {
        SessionFactory.get( { token : token },
            function success(response, responseHeaders) {
                $rootScope.user = response;

                $rootScope.ajaxCall.resolve();
            }
        );
    }
});

app.controller('UnitController', function($scope, UnitFactory) {

    $scope.ajaxCall.promise.then(function() {
        $scope.updateUnits = function () {
            UnitFactory.query({fedUnit: $scope.user.fedUnit});
        }
    });
});
```

I don't use $rootScope in the controller.